# Why the reference error is different between Chrome and Vscode(use Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, v8

This is very simple case.
The same use case, the same v8 engine is used, but why is there a different error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are both telling you it's undefined.  The specific wording of the message is up to whoever wrote the error messages for each implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's console uses slightly special rules for some things, which I guess in this cases causes slightly different error messages to be generated. If you put the snippet `aa; let aa` into a regular script (or into an on-website shell), you'll see the "Cannot access 'aa' before initialization" message.

An example why special rules for the console are desirable: in regular code, you can't re-declare `let` variables: `let aa = 1; let aa = 2` is an error. But in the console, where we typically try various snippets, it would be annoying if we only got one shot at declaring `aa` -- that's why on the console, you can write `let aa = 1` and then `let aa = 2` and that second line *won't* throw an error.

That said: what's guaranteed is that you'll get a `ReferenceError`. The specific message afterwards is not standardized, is meant for developer convenience, and may differ in different implementations (or versions of them).